# sqldeveloper error : no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path on windows 7

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, tnsnames, ojdbc

no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path sql developer windows 7

this is my tnsnames.ora

```
89# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DOCASSIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = DOCASSIST)
    )
  )
```

this is the listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )


DOCASSISTLISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

this is the sqlnet.ora

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

the tns ping gives me this

```
C:\Users\Manish>tnsping docassist

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 01-FEB-2
014 22:09:31

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
M:\app\oracleuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DOCASSIST)))
OK (0 msec)
```

I also created environment variable ORACLE_HOME pointing to the tnsnames folder  /NETWORK/ADMIN

Appreciate your help.

Comment: [This](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2319271) might interest you!

Answer (score 6):

Your path of directory Tnsnames is incorrect, check it in Tools\Preferences\Data Base\Avanced:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Same like Angel but in English:
Go to:

Tools->Preferences-> Database-> Advanced then go to the **tnsnames**.oRA folder

C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin

[image]